# User control that will internally calculate how much text to show

Tags: user-controls

I want to develop an user control using Windows.Forms.Label that will internally calculate how much text to show based on the current height and length of the control.
Does anybody have the solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to put a `Label` on your `UserControl`, and set it to `Dock` to fill. Set the label's `Autosize` to false.

If you want to go a step further and an ellipsis to your label, you'll need to look into `Graphics.MeasureString`.

Comment: I did the same procedure and also used Graphics.MeasureString but what I want to calculate how many texts that label will contain against font and size of the label. Then based on the number of text i want to write logic to show the link label to that user control. How can I do that ? Do you have any solution. Please suggest.